# Quarto PDF not rendering

Tags: eqnarray, quarto

My Quarto PDF isn't rendering!

Here is the error output in the terminal once I press "Render" in RStudio:

```
pandoc 
  to: pdf
  output-file: LearningLaTeX.pdf
  standalone: true
  pdf-engine: latexmk
  variables:
    graphics: true
    tables: true
  default-image-extension: pdf
  toc: true
  
metadata
  documentclass: scrartcl
  classoption:
    - DIV=11
    - numbers=noendperiod
  papersize: letter
  header-includes:
    - '\KOMAoption{captions}{tableheading}'
  block-headings: true
  editor: visual
  title: Learning LaTeX
  author: Anish Goyal
  date: 'January 18, 2023'
  subtitle: A document containing a collection of mathematical expressions in LaTeX and a 'funny' meme about LaTeX for the Applications of Linear Algebra class at GSMST.
  
latexmk: security risk: running with elevated privileges
pdflatex: security risk: running with elevated privileges
Latexmk: If appropriate, the -f option can be used to get latexmk
  to try to force complete processing.
Reverting Windows console CPs to (in,out) = (437,65001)
Error producing PDF.
! Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \endgroup 
l.289 \[\begin{eqnarray}
```

Here is the Quarto source (.qmd):

```
---
title: "Learning LaTeX"
author: Anish Goyal
date: January 18, 2023
subtitle: "A document containing a collection of mathematical expressions in LaTeX and a 'funny' meme about LaTeX for the Applications of Linear Algebra class at GSMST."
format:
    pdf:
        pdf-engine: latexmk
        latex-auto-install: true
code-overflow: wrap
toc: true
---

## Mathematical expressions

### Expression 1

![](images/image-1069874928.png)

    $$
    \begin{cases}
    w + x +y +z=6 \\
    w \hspace{90px} +y+z =4 \\
    w \hspace{90px}+y \hspace{90px} =2 \\
    \end{cases}
    $$

$$
\Huge
\begin{cases}
w + x +y +z=6 \\
w \hspace{90px} +y+z =4 \\
w \hspace{90px}+y \hspace{90px} =2 \\
\end{cases}
$$

### Expression 2

![](images/image-1212342519.png)

    $$
    k\neq-1, 1 \\ {\frac{1}{k+1}},{\frac{1}{k+1}}
    $$

$$\Huge 
k\neq-1, 1 \\ {\frac{1}{k+1}},{\frac{1}{k+1}}
$$

### Expression 3

![](images/image-1884990960.png)

    $$
    \operatorname{tr}A:=\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{jj}
    $$ 

$$ 
\Huge
\operatorname{tr}A:=\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{jj}
$$

### Expression 4

![](images/image-1983034508.png)

    $$
    A(\theta)={\left[
    \begin{matrix}
    \cos{\theta} & -\sin{\theta} \\
    \sin{\theta} & \cos{\theta}
    \end{matrix}\right]}
    $$

$$ \Huge
A(\theta)={\left[
\begin{matrix}
\cos{\theta} & -\sin{\theta} \\
\sin{\theta} & \cos{\theta}
\end{matrix}\right]}
$$

### Expression 5

![](images/image-1969377765.png)

    $$
    A = \left [ \begin{matrix} 
    0 & a & a^2 & a^3 & a^4 \\
    0 & 0 & a & a^2 & a^3 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & a & a^2 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & a \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 
    \end{matrix} \right ]
    $$

$$ \Huge
A = \left [ \begin{matrix} 
0 & a & a^2 & a^3 & a^4 \\
0 & 0 & a & a^2 & a^3 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & a & a^2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & a \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\end{matrix} \right ]
$$

### Expression 6

![](images/image-1950951149.png)

    $$
    \bf{3.1.6. Proposition.} \ Let \  n \in \mathbb{N} \ and \ \bf{M}_{n \times n} \ be \ the  \ collection \ of \ all \ n \times n \ matrices. \ There \ is \ exactly \ one \\ function \\
    \mathrm{det}: \bf{M}_{n \times n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\colon A\mapsto\operatorname{det}A
    $$

$$\begin{eqnarray}
\bf{3.1.6. Proposition.} \ Let \  n \in \mathbb{N} \ and \ \bf{M}_{n \times n} \ be \ the  \ collection \ of \ all \ n \times n \ matrices. \ There \ is \ exactly \ one \ function \\
\mathrm{det}: \bf{M}_{n \times n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\colon A\mapsto\operatorname{det}A
\end{eqnarray}$$

### Expression 7

![](images/image-2143312636.png)

    $$
    \bf{3.1.12. Proposition.} \ If \  A \in \mathbb{N} \ and \ 1 \le j \le n, \ then \\
    \mathrm{det}\ A: \sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{jk}C_{jk}
    $$

$$\Large \begin{eqnarray}
\bf{3.1.12. Proposition.} \ If \  A \in \mathbb{N} \ and \ 1 \le j \le n, \ then \\
\mathrm{det}\ A: \sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{jk}C_{jk}
\end{eqnarray}$$

### Expression 8

![](images/image-1940893679.png)

    $$
    \vert a d+b e+c f\vert\leq{\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}}}{\sqrt{d^{2}+e^{2}+f^{2}}}
    $$

$$ \huge
\vert a d+b e+c f\vert\leq{\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}}}{\sqrt{d^{2}+e^{2}+f^{2}}}
$$

### Expression 9

![](images/image-331355199.png)

    $$
    \text{Let $V$ be the set of real numbers $x$ such that $x >= 0$. Define an operation of "addition" by} \\
    x \boxplus y = xy+1 \\
    \text{for all $x, y \in V$. Define an operation of "scalar multiplication" by} \\
    a \boxdot x = a^2x \\
    \text{for all $a \in R$ and $x \in V$.}
    $$

$$\begin{eqnarray}
\text{Let $V$ be the set of real numbers $x$ such that $x >= 0$. Define an operation of "addition" by} \\
x \boxplus y = xy+1 \\
\text{for all $x, y \in V$. Define an operation of "scalar multiplication" by} \\
a \boxdot x = a^2x \\
\text{for all $a \in R$ and $x \in V$.}
\end{eqnarray}$$

### Expression 10

![](images/image-1239672658.png)

    $$
    \left [ \begin{matrix} 
    0 & -\frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & : & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & : & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    \frac{1}{2} & 0 & -\frac{1}{2} & 0 & : & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & : & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{matrix} \right ] \xrightarrow{X_1}
    \left [ \begin{matrix} 
    1 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & : &  &  &  &  \\
    0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & : &  &  &  &  \\
    \frac{1}{2} & 0 & -\frac{1}{2} & 0 & : &  &  &  &  \\
    0 & -\frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & : &  &  &  &  \\
    \end{matrix} \right ] 
    $$

$$ \Large 
\left [ \begin{matrix} 
0 & -\frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & : & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & : & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\frac{1}{2} & 0 & -\frac{1}{2} & 0 & : & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & : & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{matrix} \right ] \xrightarrow{X_1}
\left [ \begin{matrix} 
1 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & : &  &  &  &  \\
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & : &  &  &  &  \\
\frac{1}{2} & 0 & -\frac{1}{2} & 0 & : &  &  &  &  \\
0 & -\frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & : &  &  &  &  \\
\end{matrix} \right ] 
$$

### Expression 11

![](images/image-966103750.png)

    $$
    a_{jk} = \begin{cases}
    0, & \text{for $\vert j-k \vert 1$} \\ 
    1, &\text{for $\vert j-k \vert = 1$} \\
    2\cos x, &\text{for $j=k$} \\
    \end{cases} 
    $$

$$ \Huge
a_{jk} = \begin{cases}
0, & \text{for $\vert j-k \vert 1$} \\ 
1, &\text{for $\vert j-k \vert = 1$} \\
2\cos x, &\text{for $j=k$} \\
\end{cases} 
$$

### Expression 12

![](images/image-698644403.png)

    $$
    \bf{4.1.3. Definition.} \text{  Let $\bf{x}$ and $\bf{y}$ be nonzero vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then $\measuredangle{(\bf{x}, \bf{y})}$, the ANGLE between $\bf{x}$ and $\bf{y}$, is defined by} \\
    \measuredangle{(\bf{x}, \bf{y})} = \arccos \frac{\langle \bf{x}, \bf{y}\rangle}{\Vert\bf{x} \Vert \Vert\bf{y} \Vert}
    $$

$$\begin{eqnarray}
\bf{4.1.3. Definition.} \text{  Let $\bf{x}$ and $\bf{y}$ be nonzero vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then $\measuredangle{(\bf{x}, \bf{y})}$, the ANGLE between $\bf{x}$ and $\bf{y}$, is defined by} \\
\measuredangle{(\bf{x}, \bf{y})} = \arccos \frac{\langle \bf{x}, \bf{y}\rangle}{\Vert\bf{x} \Vert \Vert\bf{y} \Vert}
\end{eqnarray}$$

### Expression 13

![](images/image-1340050623.png)

    $$
    M\cap N \\
    M\cup N 
    $$

$$ \huge \begin{eqnarray} 
M\cap N \\
M\cup N 
\end{eqnarray} $$

### Expression 14

![](images/image-341248740.png)

    $$
    \int_{0}^{1}t g(t)\,d t=0 \hspace{50pt} \text{and} \hspace{50pt} \int_{0}^{1}t^{4}g(t)\,d t=0
    $$

$$ \huge \begin{eqnarray}
\int_{0}^{1}t g(t)\,d t=0 \hspace{50pt} \text{and} \hspace{50pt} \int_{0}^{1}t^{4}g(t)\,d t=0
\end{eqnarray}$$

### Expression 15

![](images/image-1876561767.png)

    $$
    \mathbf{y}=\left(-{\frac{1}{2}},{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}\right)
    $$

$$ \huge
\mathbf{y}=\left(-{\frac{1}{2}},{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}\right)
$$

## A LaTeX Meme

![](images/image-220842989.png)
```

Here is the actual LaTeX (.tex) file produced:

```
% Options for packages loaded elsewhere
\PassOptionsToPackage{unicode}{hyperref}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names}{xcolor}
%
\documentclass[
  letterpaper,
  DIV=11,
  numbers=noendperiod]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{iftex}
\ifPDFTeX
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{textcomp} % provide euro and other symbols
\else % if luatex or xetex
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  \defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
  \defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily]{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=1}
\fi
% Use upquote if available, for straight quotes in verbatim environments
\IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\usepackage{upquote}}{}
\IfFileExists{microtype.sty}{% use microtype if available
  \usepackage[]{microtype}
  \UseMicrotypeSet[protrusion]{basicmath} % disable protrusion for tt fonts
}{}
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{KOMAClassName}{% if non-KOMA class
  \IfFileExists{parskip.sty}{%
    \usepackage{parskip}
  }{% else
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    \setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}}
}{% if KOMA class
  \KOMAoptions{parskip=half}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{xcolor}
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em} % prevent overfull lines
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-\maxdimen} % remove section numbering
% Make \paragraph and \subparagraph free-standing
\ifx\paragraph\undefined\else
  \let\oldparagraph\paragraph
  \renewcommand{\paragraph}[1]{\oldparagraph{#1}\mbox{}}
\fi
\ifx\subparagraph\undefined\else
  \let\oldsubparagraph\subparagraph
  \renewcommand{\subparagraph}[1]{\oldsubparagraph{#1}\mbox{}}
\fi


\providecommand{\tightlist}{%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}\usepackage{longtable,booktabs,array}
\usepackage{calc} % for calculating minipage widths
% Correct order of tables after \paragraph or \subparagraph
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\longtable{\par}{\if@noskipsec\mbox{}\fi\par}{}{}
\makeatother
% Allow footnotes in longtable head/foot
\IfFileExists{footnotehyper.sty}{\usepackage{footnotehyper}}{\usepackage{footnote}}
\makesavenoteenv{longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\makeatletter
\def\maxwidth{\ifdim\Gin@nat@width>\linewidth\linewidth\else\Gin@nat@width\fi}
\def\maxheight{\ifdim\Gin@nat@height>\textheight\textheight\else\Gin@nat@height\fi}
\makeatother
% Scale images if necessary, so that they will not overflow the page
% margins by default, and it is still possible to overwrite the defaults
% using explicit options in \includegraphics[width, height, ...]{}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\maxwidth,height=\maxheight,keepaspectratio}
% Set default figure placement to htbp
\makeatletter
\def\fps@figure{htbp}
\makeatother

\KOMAoption{captions}{tableheading}
\makeatletter
\makeatother
\makeatletter
\makeatother
\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{caption}{}{\usepackage{caption}}
\AtBeginDocument{%
\ifdefined\contentsname
  \renewcommand*\contentsname{Table of contents}
\else
  \newcommand\contentsname{Table of contents}
\fi
\ifdefined\listfigurename
  \renewcommand*\listfigurename{List of Figures}
\else
  \newcommand\listfigurename{List of Figures}
\fi
\ifdefined\listtablename
  \renewcommand*\listtablename{List of Tables}
\else
  \newcommand\listtablename{List of Tables}
\fi
\ifdefined\figurename
  \renewcommand*\figurename{Figure}
\else
  \newcommand\figurename{Figure}
\fi
\ifdefined\tablename
  \renewcommand*\tablename{Table}
\else
  \newcommand\tablename{Table}
\fi
}
\@ifpackageloaded{float}{}{\usepackage{float}}
\floatstyle{ruled}
\@ifundefined{c@chapter}{\newfloat{codelisting}{h}{lop}}{\newfloat{codelisting}{h}{lop}[chapter]}
\floatname{codelisting}{Listing}
\newcommand*\listoflistings{\listof{codelisting}{List of Listings}}
\makeatother
\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{caption}{}{\usepackage{caption}}
\@ifpackageloaded{subcaption}{}{\usepackage{subcaption}}
\makeatother
\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{tcolorbox}{}{\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}}
\makeatother
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{shadecolor}{\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{.97, .97, .97}}
\makeatother
\makeatletter
\makeatother
\ifLuaTeX
  \usepackage{selnolig}  % disable illegal ligatures
\fi
\IfFileExists{bookmark.sty}{\usepackage{bookmark}}{\usepackage{hyperref}}
\IfFileExists{xurl.sty}{\usepackage{xurl}}{} % add URL line breaks if available
\urlstyle{same} % disable monospaced font for URLs
\hypersetup{
  pdftitle={Learning LaTeX},
  pdfauthor={Anish Goyal},
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor={blue},
  filecolor={Maroon},
  citecolor={Blue},
  urlcolor={Blue},
  pdfcreator={LaTeX via pandoc}}

\title{Learning LaTeX}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\providecommand{\subtitle}[1]{% add subtitle to \maketitle
  \apptocmd{\@title}{\par {\large #1 \par}}{}{}
}
\makeatother
\subtitle{A document containing a collection of mathematical expressions
in LaTeX and a `funny' meme about LaTeX for the Applications of Linear
Algebra class at GSMST.}
\author{Anish Goyal}
\date{1/18/23}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\ifdefined\Shaded\renewenvironment{Shaded}{\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, interior hidden, borderline west={3pt}{0pt}{shadecolor}, breakable, frame hidden, boxrule=0pt, sharp corners]}{\end{tcolorbox}}\fi

\renewcommand*\contentsname{Table of contents}
{
\hypersetup{linkcolor=}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\tableofcontents
}
\hypertarget{mathematical-expressions}{%
\subsection{Mathematical expressions}\label{mathematical-expressions}}

\hypertarget{expression-1}{%
\subsubsection{Expression 1}\label{expression-1}}

\includegraphics{images/image-1069874928.png}

\begin{verbatim}
$$
\begin{cases}
w + x +y +z=6 \\
w \hspace{90px} +y+z =4 \\
w \hspace{90px}+y \hspace{90px} =2 \\
\end{cases}
$$
\end{verbatim}

\[
\Huge
\begin{cases}
w + x +y +z=6 \\
w \hspace{90px} +y+z =4 \\
w \hspace{90px}+y \hspace{90px} =2 \\
\end{cases}
\]

\hypertarget{expression-2}{%
\subsubsection{Expression 2}\label{expression-2}}

\includegraphics{images/image-1212342519.png}

\begin{verbatim}
$$
k\neq-1, 1 \\ {\frac{1}{k+1}},{\frac{1}{k+1}}
$$
\end{verbatim}

\[\Huge 
k\neq-1, 1 \\ {\frac{1}{k+1}},{\frac{1}{k+1}}
\]

\hypertarget{expression-3}{%
\subsubsection{Expression 3}\label{expression-3}}

\includegraphics{images/image-1884990960.png}

\begin{verbatim}
$$
\operatorname{tr}A:=\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{jj}
$$ 
\end{verbatim}

\[ 
\Huge
\operatorname{tr}A:=\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{jj}
\]

\hypertarget{expression-4}{%
\subsubsection{Expression 4}\label{expression-4}}

\includegraphics{images/image-1983034508.png}

\begin{verbatim}
$$
A(\theta)={\left[
\begin{matrix}
\cos{\theta} & -\sin{\theta} \\
\sin{\theta} & \cos{\theta}
\end{matrix}\right]}
$$
\end{verbatim}

\[ \Huge
A(\theta)={\left[
\begin{matrix}
\cos{\theta} & -\sin{\theta} \\
\sin{\theta} & \cos{\theta}
\end{matrix}\right]}
\]

\hypertarget{expression-5}{%
\subsubsection{Expression 5}\label{expression-5}}

\includegraphics{images/image-1969377765.png}

\begin{verbatim}
$$
A = \left [ \begin{matrix} 
0 & a & a^2 & a^3 & a^4 \\
0 & 0 & a & a^2 & a^3 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & a & a^2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & a \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\end{matrix} \right ]
$$
\end{verbatim}

\[ \Huge
A = \left [ \begin{matrix} 
0 & a & a^2 & a^3 & a^4 \\
0 & 0 & a & a^2 & a^3 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & a & a^2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & a \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\end{matrix} \right ]
\]

\hypertarget{expression-6}{%
\subsubsection{Expression 6}\label{expression-6}}

\includegraphics{images/image-1950951149.png}

\begin{verbatim}
$$
\textbf{3.1.6. Proposition.} \ Let \  n \in \mathbb{N} \ and \ \textbf{M}_{n \times n} \ be \ the  \ collection \ of \ all \ n \times n \ matrices. \ There \ is \ exactly \ one \\ function \\
\mathrm{det}: \textbf{M}_{n \times n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\colon A\mapsto\operatorname{det}A
$$
\end{verbatim}

\[
\textbf{3.1.6. Proposition.} \ Let \  n \in \mathbb{N} \ and \ \textbf{M}_{n \times n} \ be \ the  \ collection \ of \ all \ n \times n \ matrices. \ There \ is \ exactly \ one \ function \\
\mathrm{det}: \textbf{M}_{n \times n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\colon A\mapsto\operatorname{det}A
\]

\hypertarget{expression-7}{%
\subsubsection{Expression 7}\label{expression-7}}

\includegraphics{images/image-2143312636.png}

\begin{verbatim}
$$
\textbf{3.1.12. Proposition.} \ If \  A \in \mathbb{N} \ and \ 1 \le j \le n, \ then \\
\mathrm{det}\ A: \sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{jk}C_{jk}
$$
\end{verbatim}

\[\Large \begin{eqnarray}
\textbf{3.1.12. Proposition.} \ If \  A \in \mathbb{N} \ and \ 1 \le j \le n, \ then \\
\mathrm{det}\ A: \sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{jk}C_{jk}
\end{eqnarray}\]

\hypertarget{expression-8}{%
\subsubsection{Expression 8}\label{expression-8}}

\includegraphics{images/image-1940893679.png}

\begin{verbatim}
$$
\vert a d+b e+c f\vert\leq{\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}}}{\sqrt{d^{2}+e^{2}+f^{2}}}
$$
\end{verbatim}

\[ \huge
\vert a d+b e+c f\vert\leq{\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}}}{\sqrt{d^{2}+e^{2}+f^{2}}}
\]

\hypertarget{expression-9}{%
\subsubsection{Expression 9}\label{expression-9}}

\includegraphics{images/image-331355199.png}

\begin{verbatim}
$$
\text{Let $V$ be the set of real numbers $x$ such that $x >= 0$. Define an operation of "addition" by} \\
x \boxplus y = xy+1 \\
\text{for all $x, y \in V$. Define an operation of "scalar multiplication" by} \\
a \boxdot x = a^2x \\
\text{for all $a \in R$ and $x \in V$.}
$$
\end{verbatim}

\[\begin{eqnarray}
\text{Let $V$ be the set of real numbers $x$ such that $x >= 0$. Define an operation of "addition" by} \\
x \boxplus y = xy+1 \\
\text{for all $x, y \in V$. Define an operation of "scalar multiplication" by} \\
a \boxdot x = a^2x \\
\text{for all $a \in R$ and $x \in V$.}
\end{eqnarray}\]

\hypertarget{expression-10}{%
\subsubsection{Expression 10}\label{expression-10}}

\includegraphics{images/image-1239672658.png}

\begin{verbatim}
$$
\left [ \begin{matrix} 
0 & -\frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & : & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & : & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\frac{1}{2} & 0 & -\frac{1}{2} & 0 & : & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & : & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{matrix} \right ] \xrightarrow{X_1}
\left [ \begin{matrix} 
1 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & : &  &  &  &  \\
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & : &  &  &  &  \\
\frac{1}{2} & 0 & -\frac{1}{2} & 0 & : &  &  &  &  \\
0 & -\frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & : &  &  &  &  \\
\end{matrix} \right ] 
$$
\end{verbatim}

\[ \Large 
\left [ \begin{matrix} 
0 & -\frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & : & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & : & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\frac{1}{2} & 0 & -\frac{1}{2} & 0 & : & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & : & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{matrix} \right ] \xrightarrow{X_1}
\left [ \begin{matrix} 
1 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & : &  &  &  &  \\
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & : &  &  &  &  \\
\frac{1}{2} & 0 & -\frac{1}{2} & 0 & : &  &  &  &  \\
0 & -\frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & : &  &  &  &  \\
\end{matrix} \right ] 
\]

\hypertarget{expression-11}{%
\subsubsection{Expression 11}\label{expression-11}}

\includegraphics{images/image-966103750.png}

\begin{verbatim}
$$
a_{jk} = \begin{cases}
0, & \text{for $\vert j-k \vert 1$} \\ 
1, &\text{for $\vert j-k \vert = 1$} \\
2\cos x, &\text{for $j=k$} \\
\end{cases} 
$$
\end{verbatim}

\[ \Huge
a_{jk} = \begin{cases}
0, & \text{for $\vert j-k \vert 1$} \\ 
1, &\text{for $\vert j-k \vert = 1$} \\
2\cos x, &\text{for $j=k$} \\
\end{cases} 
\]

\hypertarget{expression-12}{%
\subsubsection{Expression 12}\label{expression-12}}

\includegraphics{images/image-698644403.png}

\begin{verbatim}
$$
\textbf{4.1.3. Definition.} \text{  Let $\textbf{x}$ and $\textbf{y}$ be nonzero vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then $\measuredangle{(\textbf{x}, \textbf{y})}$, the ANGLE between $\textbf{x}$ and $\textbf{y}$, is defined by} \\
\measuredangle{(\textbf{x}, \textbf{y})} = \arccos \frac{\langle \textbf{x}, \textbf{y}\rangle}{\Vert\textbf{x} \Vert \Vert\textbf{y} \Vert}
$$
\end{verbatim}

\[\begin{eqnarray}
\textbf{4.1.3. Definition.} \text{  Let $\textbf{x}$ and $\textbf{y}$ be nonzero vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then $\measuredangle{(\textbf{x}, \textbf{y})}$, the ANGLE between $\textbf{x}$ and $\textbf{y}$, is defined by} \\
\measuredangle{(\textbf{x}, \textbf{y})} = \arccos \frac{\langle \textbf{x}, \textbf{y}\rangle}{\Vert\textbf{x} \Vert \Vert\textbf{y} \Vert}
\end{eqnarray}\]

\hypertarget{expression-13}{%
\subsubsection{Expression 13}\label{expression-13}}

\includegraphics{images/image-1340050623.png}

\begin{verbatim}
$$
M\cap N \\
M\cup N 
$$
\end{verbatim}

\[ \huge \begin{eqnarray} 
M\cap N \\
M\cup N 
\end{eqnarray} \]

\hypertarget{expression-14}{%
\subsubsection{Expression 14}\label{expression-14}}

\includegraphics{images/image-341248740.png}

\begin{verbatim}
$$
\int_{0}^{1}t g(t)\,d t=0 \hspace{50pt} \text{and} \hspace{50pt} \int_{0}^{1}t^{4}g(t)\,d t=0
$$
\end{verbatim}

\[ \huge \begin{eqnarray}
\int_{0}^{1}t g(t)\,d t=0 \hspace{50pt} \text{and} \hspace{50pt} \int_{0}^{1}t^{4}g(t)\,d t=0
\end{eqnarray}\]

\hypertarget{expression-15}{%
\subsubsection{Expression 15}\label{expression-15}}

\includegraphics{images/image-1876561767.png}

\begin{verbatim}
$$
\mathbf{y}=\left(-{\frac{1}{2}},{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}\right)
$$
\end{verbatim}

\[ \huge
\mathbf{y}=\left(-{\frac{1}{2}},{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}\right)
\]

\hypertarget{a-latex-meme}{%
\subsection{A LaTeX Meme}\label{a-latex-meme}}

\includegraphics{images/image-220842989.png}



\end{document}
```

I have tried using a different pdf engine (xelatex or latexmk), to no avail! I have tried getting rid of the equation array and it still doesn't work. I also tried using RStudio instead of VS Code to render this file, and it didn't work.

Comment: x-post https://stackoverflow.com/q/75745323/2777074

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error messages you get are from nesting math environments, like `eqnarray` into other math environments like `$$...$$` and `\[...\]`, usage of outdated font commands like `\bf` with a koma class etc.

---

However instead of fixing these problems, you shouldn't abuse math environments to type whole sentences to begin with. Instead have a look at the various theorem packages to properly set your theorem-like parts (e.g. your propositions). Here an example with the `amsthm` package:

```
---
title: "Learning LaTeX"
author: Anish Goyal
date: January 18, 2023
subtitle: "A document containing a collection of mathematical expressions in LaTeX and a 'funny' meme about LaTeX for the Applications of Linear Algebra class at GSMST."
format:
    pdf:
        pdf-engine: latexmk
        latex-auto-install: true
code-overflow: wrap
toc: true
header-includes:
- \usepackage{amsthm}
- \newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
---

\begin{proposition}
If $A \in \mathbb{N}$ and $1 \le j \le n$, then 
\begin{equation}
\det A: \sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{jk}C_{jk}
\end{equation}
\end{proposition}
```

[image]